# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отфильтровать в листе дубликаты юзеров по возрасту через streamAPI

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Есть класс User

```
public class User {
    String name;
    Integer age;

    public User(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Как отфильтровать в листе дубликаты юзеров по возрасту, чтобы получился вывод, как в строке "expected" через streamAPI в одну строчку, без использования сторонних библиотек, без использования вспомогательных методов, без изменения структуры класса User?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

           List<User> list1 = asList(new User("Misha", 1),
                                      new User("Vova", 33),
                                      new User("Vova", 33),
                                      new User("Peter", 2));

            // try that: List<User> res = list1.stream().flatMap(User::getAge).distinct().flatMap(User::getClass).collect(Collectors.toList());
            // expected: [User("Misha", 1),User("Vova", 33), User("Peter", 2), )]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<User> list1 = Arrays.asList(new User("Misha", 1),
            new User("Vova", 33),
            new User("Vova", 33),
            new User("Peter", 2)
    );
    list1.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(u -> u.age))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            // в каждой группе берется первый элемент,
            // так как все остальные будут дубликатами
            .map(e -> e.getValue().get(0))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```